# Always show service in contextual menu

Tags: applescript, automator, bash, services

Sometimes when I create a service in Automator, I want it to always appear in the Finder contextual menu, not just when I have a selected a file or folder.
The services are always either pure applescript or pure bash, so if it can be done some other way without using Automator, I'm also satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I've mentioned before that the commercial utility Unsanity [FruitMenu](http://www.unsanity.com/haxies/fruitmenu) allows customization of Finder *contextual* menus. You could launch an AppleScript or Automator document from the contextual menu with this utility. But FruitMenu requires Rosetta and therefore won't work in Lion. I don't know if Unsanity is developing a way to implement this in Lion, or not.

Comment: I'm using Lion, so this won't work as you said.